# does microsoft have its own external grid controls?

Tags: .net, grid, controls

Except those which are available in Visual Studio, are there any official external Microsoft's grid controls? For example, Telerik has controls for .net. Does Microsoft have similar ones?

EDIT: It's for webforms...

Thanks,
Ilija

Comment: sorry, i forgot to write: it's for webforms

Comment: Webforms is an abstraction provided by ASP.NET.  It doesn't make sense to talk about "external" when you're looking for controls that *have* to run on ASP.NET to be functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls you reference (like Telerik) are made to be used inside of VS with .Net. Since Microsoft built .Net (and VS) they had no reasons to make 'external' controls.

If you look around places like CodePlex and Sourceforge then you can find 'external' grids, but most of them are not offically supported Microsoft controls.